# find count of elements contains in both collections

Tags: c#, linq

For example, we have two collections:

```
coll1 = {1,2,3,4,5}
coll2 = {3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

How to find count of elements contains in both collections(best performance)?
For example above the result must be equal `3`.

Thanks,

Comment: Are both collections known to be sorted? If so, you might be able to improve on the performance of `Intersect` by walking both enumerators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
coll1.Intersect(coll2 ).Count()
```